# iText7 Allow User to Edit Text

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, itext7

I'm looking to allow users to edit text that I am inserting in a rectangle. It appears that right-click > edit text works, but it's a pretty clunky solution. I've looked through the properties of text, paragraph, canvas and rectangle but I'm not seeing anything that fits this. I've also looked into adding text-boxes to the rectangle but that's not exactly what I'm looking for.

The goal would be to let the user click on the text below and edit in-rectangle.
[image]

The code for the last bit:

```
Text conclusionTitle = new Text("CONCLUSION:\n").SetFontSize(7).SetFontColor(ColorConstants.RED).SetBold();
            Text conclusionMessage = new Text("[Insert response here]").SetFontSize(6).SetFontColor(ColorConstants.RED);
            Paragraph conclusionParagraph = new Paragraph().Add(conclusionTitle).Add(conclusionMessage);
```

Comment: You should consider using form fields.

Comment: Mhhh... not really what I'm going for in this instance. Can you even put form fields within a rectangle/canvas?

Comment: Form fields visualizations are annotations. Thus,  they are not in a page canvas but kind of hover above. What you put into a page canvas is static, not editable in a normal pdf viewer. Form fields are for content a user can edit.

Comment: @mkl So you can overlay a form field on a canvas/rectangle?

Comment: You set position and size of a form field, and then it's over whatever is drawn in the page content canvas there.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow the user to edit the text of a PDF you have a few options. You can either create a FreeTextAnnotation or you can create a form field that allows user-input. (i.e. CreateText or CreateMultiLineText).